# Negative numbers with exponents in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, exponent, negative-number

Why does Python give me 2 different answers for the following?

```
print(-1**2)   # prints -1 
print((-1)**2) # prints 1
```

Comment: The order of operations are different

Comment: That is a trivial math problem: `-1**2 = - (1**2) = - (1x1) = -1`, and `(-1)**2 = (-1)*(-1) = 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python parses `print(-1**2)` in the following order:

1. Get's the exponent of `1 ** 2`
2. Negates the result.

So it becomes this:

```
>>> -(1 ** 2)
-1
>>>
```

Because `-1` translates to `print(0 - 1 ** 2)`. But in the order of operations table, `**` (exponents) is higher ranking than `-`.

Therefore, Python math follows the order of operations in regular math, `**` is more powerful (has more priority over) `-`.

As mentioned on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations):

> The acronym PEMDAS is common. It stands for Parentheses, Exponents, Multiplication/Division, Addition/Subtraction.

Also mentioned on the [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence):

| Operator | Description |
| --- | --- |
| (expressions...), [expressions...], {key: value...}, {expressions...} | Binding or parenthesized expression, list display, dictionary display, set display |
| x[index], x[index:index], x(arguments...), x.attribute | Subscription, slicing, call, attribute reference |
| await x | Await expression |
| ** | Exponentiation |
| +x, -x, ~x | Positive, negative, bitwise NOT |
| *, @, /, //, % | Multiplication, matrix multiplication, division, floor division, remainder 6 |

Answer (score 2):

The `**` operator has [precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) over `-`, so `-1**2` is in fact `-(1**2)`

List of operator precedence in python from highest precedence (top) to lowest precedence (bottom):

| Operator | Function |
| --- | --- |
| () | Parentheses (grouping) |
| f(args...) | Function call |
| x[index:index] | Slicing |
| x[index] | Subscription |
| x.attribute | Attribute reference |
| ** | Exponentiation |
| ~x | Bitwise not |
| +x, -x | Positive, negative |
| *, /, % | Multiplication, division, remainder |
| +, - | Addition, subtraction |
| <<, >> | Bitwise shifts |
| & | Bitwise AND |
| ^ | Bitwise XOR |
| | | Bitwise OR |
| in, not in, is, is not, <, <=, >, >=, <>, !=, == | Comparisons, membership, identity |
| not x | Boolean NOT |
| and | Boolean AND |
| or | Boolean OR |
| lambda | Lambda expression |